# Apple app store release fastlane fails because of credentials | I am using API authentication

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, app-store-connect, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, fastlane

My azure release pipeline for an app store release uses App Store Connect API key for the authentication method. All the details are filled in correctly and I have had successful releases in the past with the same configuration.

Suddenly today the pipeline fails and the error points to missing credentials, I would appreciate it if someone pointed me in the right direction to resolve this.

*Error*

```
/Users/runner/.gem-cache/gems/fastlane-2.184.1/credentials_manager/lib/credentials_manager/account_manager.rb:125:in `ask_for_login': [!] Missing username, and running in non-interactive shell (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out its currently an open fastlane issue with Azure DevOps release to Apple App Store. The workaround is to remove the App Specific ID value from the release pipeline tasks. See the below link for more:
https://github.com/microsoft/app-store-vsts-extension/issues/244

Answer (score 0):

you have to sign again with your apple account into the pipeline credentials. It has a limited time life for the password now

Comment: How do I do that please?

Comment: You can go to Account Settings, and under your profile, you'll see the Developers account. Usually, it shows you one banner with the login...

Comment: I am confused, are you talking about on Azure Dev Ops or Apple Store Connect? Can you please break down the steps a little simpler? thanks for your patience

Comment: it is in Azure, but I think I saw the steps on AppCenter instead of AzureDevOps. On AzureDevOps maybe you have to go first into apple, but I found this article about what you have to do to be able to use your pipeline again.
[link]https://progrunning.net/app-store-connect-api-with-azure-dev-ops-and-fastlane/